# Is there some logout hook in Plone 4?

Tags: plone, logout, plone-4.x

I have a Plone-4.3-based site which provides access to another site as well: Whenever someone logs in to my site, (s)he can click on special hyperlinks and proceed to that other site without the need to enter a password there (some kind of simple SSO, based on a ReST interface).

Now I have the need to logout the user from that other site whenever (s)he logs out from my own site, e.g. by sending a special request which is of course not the topic of this question (perhaps it still needs to be implemented, because session expiration used to be good enough.)

How would I accomplish this, to be precise: **Where would I hook in that secondary logout code?** Is there some kind of logout hook, or should I modify some `logout.[c]py` view? I couldn't find no event nor category mentioned in the [Event types section here](https://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/components/events.html#event-types).

Comment: I posted a link to your question in our forum https://community.plone.org/t/stack-overflow-is-there-some-logout-hook-in-plone-4/4172

Comment: Thank you. I posted there the code I use now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the `Products.PlonePAS.events.UserLoggedOutEvent` for such purposes.

As an example, it is explained at the [Events Section of the Plone Addon Developer Guide](https://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/components/events.html#subscribing-using-zcml)

Comment: That example in the developer guide registers the handler for the event class, rather than an interface. Is that really correct? I thought the registrations always have to be against an interface (as they are in the other examples).

Comment: @Jens: Ah, thank you. I missed that one because it is not mentioned in the [Event types](https://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/components/events.html#event-types) section.

Comment: @Petri it is cleaner to use the interface, right, but it works both.